# Rails server does not take in account the production and still used development db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

since several days I have this problem:

For a few days it has worked and now I can't do it works again. I setup a rails server on ubuntu with apache-2.  I used a git repository to get all new change. After I run
               sudo rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production

But after have restart apache server I can see that rails use the development db and not the production while before it has used it.

I don't really understand what can cause this. So i really appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. In apache sites configuration I had RailsEnv development instead of production.
But now I have another problem: rails does not start due to

*** Exception ArgumentError in
PhusionPassenger::Railz::ApplicationSpawner (No association found for
name `machines'. Has it been defined yet?) (process 16052):
 from
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:245:in`
accepts_nested_attributes_for'
 from
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:222:in
`each'
 from
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:222:in`
accepts_nested_attributes_for'
 from /home/et1/wip3/sophia/app/models/machines_operatingsystem.rb:2

But I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
env RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

You can also add the following line to your `$HOME/.bash_profile`:

```
export RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: Have you, by any chance, ran `bundler --without production` or anything similar on the development box?

Comment: Is there a configuration file or whatever that I can check to be sure that I do not ran bundler --without production

Comment: Yes, if you ran it, there should be a `.bundle` or `.bundler` folder at your application's root.

Comment: But if I remember correctly I made a mistake in the paste. I run this command on my development repository. So maybe it explain the problem. But is there a way to fix it. I precise that in my development repository db is still using development.squilite3

Comment: I've tried several things to understand and fix the problem. I don't know why it still using development db.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'development'` or just `RAILS_ENV='development'` somewhere?

Comment: in initializer.rb I can see RAILS_ENV = (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || 'development').dup unless defined?(RAILS_ENV). This is the only things that I found in my project.

Comment: More info: While I'm trying to understand the problem I note something: When I execute rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production I can see that it create me the production db. But if I add new value in db I can see it still used development. I'm continuing my search on google :D. But if someone knows the answer ...